# Comparing values between maps

Tags: apex, map

I would like to update my exsiting code that uses Lists to instead use maps.
Here is what I have:

```
List<object1__c> records1 = new List<object1__c>();
List<object2__c> records2 = new List<object2__c>();

records1 = [SELECT id, name from object1__c ];
records2 = [SELECT id, name from object2__c];
    
    
 Object3__c result1 = (Object3__c ) so;

    if(!records1.isEmpty() && !records2.isEmpty()){
        for (object1__c rec: records1) {
            for(object2__c rec2: record2)
            if (rec.Apple__c == rec2.Pear__c){
                rec.Job_Item__c = result1.Id;
     
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to convert the above to use maps but I am not sure on how to compare the fields between the 2 maps.  Would the below code work or Do I need to iterate through both maps?  Just trying to reduce the number of for loops:

```
Map<Id,object1__c> records1 = new Map<Id,object1__c>();
Map<Id,object2__c> records2 = new Map<Id,object2__c>();

Object3__c result1 = (Object3__c ) so;

if(!records1.isEmpty() && !records2.isEmpty()){

    for(object1__c  rec1 : records1.values()){
        if (rec1.Apple__c = records2.getvalues(Pear_c)){
            rec1.Test__c = result1.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worthy of note:  You don't need to check if a map or a list is empty before using it in a loop (the only thing you need to worry about is if the collection is `null`). If you attempt to loop over an empty collection, the loop will see that there's nothing to loop over and automatically skip executing the code inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key of the map of the records that you're comparing against needs to be it's field value that you're using for comparison.

So if you're comparing records1 Apple__c to records2 Pear__c, you need a map of records2 by its Pear__c value. For example

```
Map<String, Object2__c> object2ByPear = new Map<String, Object2__c>();
for (Object2__c record2 : records2) {
  object2ByPear.put(record2.Pear__c, record2);
}
```

Then you can loop through a list of records1 and compare using the object2ByPear map.

```
for (Object1__c record1 : records1) {
  if (object2ByPear.containsKey(record1.Apple__c)) {
    Object2__c matchingRecord2 = object2ByPear.get(record1.Apple__c);
    // to something
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  To confirm.  The original 2 maps cannot be directly compared to each other(it is not in the above code but each map is being populated by a SOQL query ).  The variables for the 'for' loop are the same as the maps but this was done for simplicity purposes.  Just want to make sure I am understanding the solution you are providing.